# Run function only if event default is/isn't prevented

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, preventdefault

Is there a way to run a function only if `event.preventDefault()` is called on an event (by another unknown function). This is for a jQuery plugin, so I don't have any knowledge of what other parts of the page might be doing. I've tried this:

```
Event.test = Event.preventDefault;
Event.preventDefault = function () {
    alert('Success');
    this.test();
}
```

but it doesn't work... just behaves as normal, with no errors.

Conversely, I want the opposite too... to call a function only if `event.preventDefault()` isn't called. In effect, to add a function to the default action for an event. Any ideas? Is all this at all possible?

Edit: Based on the comment, I've got a solution to the first problem: http://jsfiddle.net/nathan/VAePB/9/. It works in Chrome (alerts `function preventDefault() { [native code] }`, but IE alerts `undefined`. So IE won't let me define `Event.prototype.test`, but it will let me redefine `Event.prototype.preventDefault`. Weird. I'm sure I can come up with a solution to the the second problem based on this one if I can just get it to work in IE.

Comment: You might see what you can achieve by messing with "preventDefault" on `Event.prototype` instead of `Event` - probably won't work in IE however

Comment: @Pointy Thanks. Works in Chrome. It half-works in IE8... IE runs my new function, but doesn't prevent the default, which is a little annoying. There must be a way around it, surely.

Comment: Wow, IE has some crappy behavior when dealing with this problem...  I even recreated the preventDefault method as a new function called test that just returns false.  No dice.

Comment: did you just call test, or did you return its return value? i've done that one before. <stupid ruby Procs>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, try something like this:

```
oldPreventDefault = Event.prototype.preventDefault;
Event.prototype.preventDefault = function() {
    //do stuff
    oldPreventDefault.call(this);
}
```

I don't know if that will work, but it might be worth a shot.

For the second problem, I would try something similar to live event handling. Put a listener on a parent element (i.e. `body` or a top-level `div`). If you can get your hook into `preventDefault` as noted before, you can use that to set a flag. If the event bubbles up to that element and your flag isn't set, do your extended behavior. Though this won't work with all events, since not all events bubble. Another way to tackle this problem might be to delay execution until the current stack has finished using `setTimeout(0,...)` and then checking the flag.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I've understand. Can't you just use `event.isDefaultPrevented()` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VAePB/23/)